# Is it possible to write a function of signature `Monad m => m a -> forall r. m r` such that the original return value is preserved?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

If such a function is dependent on the choice of the monad, please demonstrate with `Maybe`. In which case the signature would be:

```
mayall :: Maybe a -> forall r. Maybe r
```

But once again, if a general implementation is possible it'd be much appreciated. The key here is that the result has to be `Maybe r`, not some specific data constructor, such as `Maybe Item` for some

```
data Item = forall r. Show r => Item r
```

If an implementation is not possible, could some alternate signature:

```
`Monad m => m a -> forall r. n r`
```

be satisfied?

In the above case, `n` is not necessarily a monad, and if it is, it could be the same as `m`

Comment: What do you mean by your edit: "such that the original return value is preserved"? Do you mean that if `m` is `return someValue`, then `foo m` should also be `return someValue`? Obviously that's not possible if `foo m` is supposed to be a different type than `m`.

Comment: Could `someValue` be wrapped inside another type, in a way that's different what what `Item` is doing above?

Comment: The signature as given doesn't have a sensible implementation. Can you post a real example where you would like to use such a function and with what kind of semantics and maybe we can find an alternative solution.

Comment: @chibro2 How do you expect to wrap something in, say, an `Int`? I mean if a user calls your function with `return "hello"` as the argument and accepts the result as an `Int`, what should the value of that `Int` be?

Comment: As a sanity check, consider the identity monad.

Answer (score 8):

The `forever` function from `Control.Monad` has the type you need.

```
forever :: Monad m => m a -> m b
```

Note that this is the same as

```
Monad m => m a -> forall r. m r
```

and that unifies with

```
Maybe a -> forall r. Maybe r
```

. However, I suspect that this may not be exactly what you are after. You can never actually obtain a value of type `r` from this. Either you get `Nothing` or it fails to terminate at all. Similarly, `const Nothing` also has the type you are asking for, and it "agrees" with `forever` in that if both terminate then they will have the same results.

All functions that have the type you are asking for can only return `Nothing` or `Just`_|_, where _|_ represents nontermination.

Answer (score 5):

One value of type `forall r. r` is `undefined`. So one way to get a value of type `Monad m => forall r. m r` is to `return undefined`. So to get a function of the type you want, you can just write:

```
foo :: Monad m => m a -> forall r. m r
foo m = m >> return undefined
```